# servr::jekyll does not render knitr-jekyll MWE correctly inside RStudio

Tags: r, jekyll, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I was trying to get Yihui's fantastic [knitr-jekyll](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-jekyll) boilerplate to work inside RStudio.

Here's what I did:

- git clone `knitr-jekyll` repo (at this [commit](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-jekyll/commit/a653a9c409b1a7b5ef1d9b5ae8366be536a28f2b))
- (If I didn't have a clean git clone, make sure `\_site` is empty and kill past rendered `2014-09-28-jekyll-with-knitr.md`)
- run `jekyll()` inside RStudio

I get this as a preview in RStudio (same in the browser):

[image: preview from within RStudio]

Oddly, now, *if I **delete** or overwrite* `\_site` and have Jekyll do the serving **on the terminal**, things work out:

```
$ jekyll serve
```

[image]

So it seems like calling Jekyll on the terminal works just fine, based on the `*.md` produced by `servr::jekyll` via `knitr`, but `servr::jekyll` somehow chokes on the styling.

I'm not sure what's going on here, or on whose end the problem might be.

Any thoughts?

---

I got:

- `jekyll 2.5.3` on the terminal
- `jekyll 1.4.3` in RStudio via `system("jekyll --version")` (**yikes! That could be the problem!**)
- `servr 0.2.0` from CRAN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, so, the `PATH` conundrum struck again: For some reason I had a stray, old `jekyll` in `/usr/bin/`, which is where RStudio looked first.

```
> system("which jekyll")
/usr/bin/jekyll
```

To fix this, I just deleted that stray, old `jekyll`, and RStudio would continue searching to `/usr/local/bin/jekyll` which is where `gem install jekyll` had apparently left it.

```
> system("which jekyll"
/usr/bin/local/jekyll
```

Done.

[image: fixed it!]

Seriously, though, I get nightmares from all things `PATH`.

Comment: Glad you figured it out by yourself.